# how to specify A record of own domain in a zonefile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, dns, domain

assuming that foobar.com is my domain, how do i specify the ip of "foobar.com" itself in my zonefile ?

Below is my sample

```
@     IN   SOA   myfoobar.com.  hostmaster.myfoobar.com. (
      2001030201 ; DB Serial Number
      10800      ; Secondary Refresh Interval
      3600       ; Secondary AXFR Retry Interval
      604800     ; Unref Secondary Expiry Interval
      86400 )    ; Minimum Time To Live

; NAME SERVICE
;
      IN  NS      ns.foobar.com.
    **IN A 192.168.1.95**  <-- do you guys mean this ?

; HOSTS WITH THIS DOMAIN NAME
;

**foorbar.com. IN A 192.168.1.95**   <--- or this will do as well ?
ns    IN A  x.x.x.x
node1 IN A  x.x.x.y  -- for node1.foobar.com
node2 IN A  x.x.x.z  -- for node2.forbar.com
```

-- how about foobar.com itself ?

Comment: Both should work without an issue.

Comment: @nKn sir, you are faster then my question. salute. and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foobar.com.  IN A X.X.X.X
```

Note that I appended a dot (`.`) to the host. This is very important since this avoids auto-appending the domain name (`foobar.com`) to the host. In your case, you didn't add the dot to node1, node2, ns... and that's why it is appended implicitly.

Comment: +1 for correctly specifying the root domain via absolute domain references

Comment: @nKn amended my zonefile with ** , can you take a look if its correct ?

Comment: @Noob that's right, that will work.

Answer (score 3):

Add the A record after the NS record.

The "@" at the beginning of the file is basically a macro that means "foobar.com". And the SOA record, even though it spans multiple lines, is really just one entry. When a line begins with whitespace instead of a domain entry, it means that it applies to the same entry as the previous line.
The top of your file looks like:

```
foobar.com   IN SOA  ...
             IN NS ns.foobar.com.
```

So just add

```
             IN A 192.168.1.95
```

or whatever your domain's IP address is.

Comment: amended my zonefile with ** , can you take a look if its correct ?

Comment: Either one of your "**" changes should do the trick. I happen to prefer the first one, but that's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

@ IN A x.x.x.x

As @arensb said, the @ represents your domain name so, in that nested set of information beneath:

```
@     IN   SOA   myfoobar.com.  hostmaster.myfoobar.com. (
  2001030201 ; DB Serial Number
  10800      ; Secondary Refresh Interval
  3600       ; Secondary AXFR Retry Interval
  604800     ; Unref Secondary Expiry Interval
  86400 )    ; Minimum Time To Live
```

You can just put:

```
IN A x.x.x.x
```

That should be all you need. So you can either include it after the SOA block or as a new line as above.

Comment: amended my zonefile with ** , can you take a look if its correct ?

Comment: Both work, glad you've got it working!